# python - Plotting data on a specific region on a map

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, plotly, matplotlib-basemap

I am just getting introduced to `mpl_toolkits.basemap` and I am  running into a wall while searching for help. The tutorials http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html is hardly of any help.

The data I have is **binary output data** and determines if a certain image was shared on social media or not. My task is to determine if the location of the picture taken has got anything to do with the share rate. While the `information gain` on latitude and longitude data has hardly any impact on the share-ability of the image, I wish to visualize all the shared and not_shared data on a map.

Here is a sample data I have(please click on `run-snippet` to see the data in tabular format),

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>GID</th>
      <th>lat</th>
      <th>long</th>
      <th>Proportion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>-1.35137</td>
      <td>36.8003</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>-1.35134</td>
      <td>36.8004</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>-1.35134</td>
      <td>36.8004</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>-1.36709</td>
      <td>36.782</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>-1.36906</td>
      <td>36.7791</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>-1.37728</td>
      <td>36.7854</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>-1.37724</td>
      <td>36.7855</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>-1.37724</td>
      <td>36.7855</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>-1.37452</td>
      <td>36.7917</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>9</th>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>-1.37452</td>
      <td>36.7917</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone help me plot the 0 points as say **red** and 1 points as **blue**.

I am also open to using other *better* visualization tools if needed. Plot.ly is something I have already used, so if plot.ly can do the job that would be great.

Comment: Never mind. I think using leaflet API folium is a much better option.